# Shall "my main amplifier is broken" be deleted?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

My main amplifier was basically not worth repairing so the question about it can be deleted as far as I'm concerned. The question is not closed but it's not relevant. I don't think the question is relevant for anybody else than myself. https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/how-to-troubleshoot-audio-imbalance

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here?

Comment: @WarriorBob I think that my question looks rather useless so I suggest we delete it. It's too localized (or something).

Comment: Your question includes some troubleshooting steps that may indeed prove useful in the future.  I see no reason to delete it.

Comment: Home theater questions are off topic, so I support deletion.

Comment: @ObscureRobot, The question _might_ be about a home theater setup, but it doesn't have to be.  The OP wasn't explicit.  In either case, the question isn't really _about_ home theater, but rather how to troubleshoot an amp/speaker setup that's malfunctioning (certainly useful in a studio environment).  Might be an edge case, but I still don't think it warrants deletion.  Just my 2 cents :)